# SQL Sum Distinct

Tags: sql, sum, distinct

I want to be able to SUM the VALUES by DISTINCT ID.  Basically in this example, I would only want to SUM IDs 1,2,3 & 4 once.  ID 1 is on the table twice but I only want to SUM it once.  The VALUES might be the same (like ID 1 & 4) but the DISTINCT should be on the ID column.

| ID | Values |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 10 |
| 2 | 20 |
| 1 | 10 |
| 3 | 30 |
| 4 | 10 |

Comment: You should provide an example of what you've already attempted.  StackOverflow is not designed for others to just do your work for you.  You'll learn best by making your own attempts first

Comment: I do not even know where to start.  I was thinking a CASE WHEN statement to determine a DISTINCT rule to sum but not sure how to write that out.

Comment: Please also specify which sql platform you want solution on. eg. SQL Server

Comment: Last part of question if quite not clear, would you mind making us clear?

i.e. The VALUES might be the same (like ID 1 & 4) but the DISTINCT should be on the ID column.

Answer (score 0):

This is straight forward group by

```
SELECT ID,SUM(VALUES)
  FROM table
GROUP BY ID
```